# Python yaml import fails with "NameError: name 'Serializer' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyyaml

I am using a python script which uses 'yaml'(pyyaml) module to serialise some files. The script was running fine for some time. Lately when I am trying to import yaml in python I am getting the following error:

[image: Serializer error]

I am not sure of the origin of the issue, since it is an external package.

Comment: We can't help fix your issue without seeing the script that is causing the errors.

Comment: Python2 is end of life. Please upgrade to Python3

Comment: I have faced this issue with the pyyaml plugin which is a older version 5.3. I installed the older version using pip and installed the new version 5.4.1, which resolved the issue.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am using Python2 because the scripts using a enterprise module which is still not moved to Python3